# Does appengine urllib use SSLv3? TLS?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, ssl, amazon-s3, urllib

When requesting an HTTPS resource, does appengine's urllib use SSLv3? use TLS? (python 2.7)

For context, AWS S3 recently announced that

> As of 12:00 AM PDT April 30, 2015, AWS will discontinue support of SSLv3 for securing connections to S3 buckets.

And that

> [some of our buckets] are currently accepting requests from clients that specify SSLv3 to connect to S3 HTTPS endpoints.

And that

> These requests will fail once AWS disables support for SSLv3 for the Amazon S3 service. To avoid interrupted access, you must update any client software (or inform any clients to update software) making the requests that are using SSLv3 to connect to S3 HTTPS endpoints.

They dont provide any user-agent information about which clients are using SSLv3. So it occurred to me that since we connect from GAE to S3 using boto 2.9.9 (which uses urllib), it's possible that our GAE to S3 connections could be the SSLv3 offenders, and now I want to check whether that's the case.

I apologize in advance if I have mis-understood some concept here. E.g. perhaps the use (or not) of TLS or SSLv3 is determined by the python version, or boto configuration, or something else. If so, please correct me, and edit my question:)

Oh, and thanks to AWS for dropping this on us w/o any user-agent info or other way to determine what exactly is going to break on April 30th ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried following code on [GAE Playground](https://cloud-playground.appspot.com/)

```
import urllib2
r = urllib2.urlopen("https://howsmyssl.com/").read()
self.response.write(r)
```

Then it said

> Your client is using TLS 1.2

I did not find any official document, but nobody tries to downgrade specification for future release.

Comment: Great idea - thanks. I actually needed it for urllib, not urllib2, so I ran that test in the same way, and it too uses TLS 1.2, as does GAE's urlfetch. Result!

Comment: Correct. Additionally, URLfetch no longer supports sslv3-only web servers for security reasons.